# Power shell how to get list of N biggest files of type text

Tags: powershell

PowerShell how to get list of N biggest files of type text ?

my goal is exactly to

- select all files that have an age over 30 days (*whatever extension
  is*)
- but ignoring any form of binary file
- sort & display the top ten biggest text/ascii files.

I spend a bunch of time for doing tries all day long yesterday around things like

```
 gci -r|sort -descending -property length | select -first 10 name, length

get-childItem .....
```

-filter and so on but no success but I a m new to powershell so ..

Comment: That line in itself should work so I'd say `with some success` . As far as excluding non ascii files goes I'm not sure what would be the most suitable way and if it's possible to avoid having to look up every single known file signature out there. You could try fiddling with `Format-Hex -Path <targetfile>` for instance but I have a feeling it'd be slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testing if a file is textual of binary is extremely hard to do, but in Windows you can use the file extensions to filter out what you don't want in the result.

```
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30).Date
# fill the list of binary filetypes that are most likely found
$binaries = '*.exe', '*.bin', '*.png', '*.gif', '*.jpg', '*.dll'  # etcetera

Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Exclude $binaries | 
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $refDate} | 
    Sort-Object Length -Descending |
    Select-Object -First 10 | 
    Select-Object Name, Length   # I would use FullName as you are using recursion..
```

Of course, you will have to add binary files that pop up in the output to th list in `$binaries` because I have just put a few examples in there now.

Comment: Thanks, I think I can adapt it now ; I understood that script.